# unable to install testng plugin in eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse-plugin, testng

getting below error while installing "Guava: Google Core Libraries for Java" cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.

Comment: Eclipse Neon is 15 releases and more than 5 years behind. There is a separate Stack Exchange for [retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Most likely Neon is much too old, but we can't say for sure with so little information.